# Jquery conflict happening with sliders in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-slider, jquery-widgets

I have the following Js files referenced in my ASP.NET project. I would like to know if there is any conflict (or duplication of JS files). Also should I upgrade any of the JS files or should I map them directly to googleapis? Please suggest as I am suspecting some conflict here.

Reason I am asking this question is because I have an ASPX page that doesn't render slider but in HTML it renders fine. I tested that using jsFiddler.

```
jquery151.min.js  
jquery-ui.min.js  
global.js  
jquery.ui.all.css  
jquery.ui.core.js  
jquery.ui.widget.js  
jquery.ui.mouse.js  
jquery.ui.slider.js  
slides.min.jquery.js
```

Comment: it is JQuery 1.5.1 not jquery151.min.js

Comment: @coder: I just checked in my project JavaScript folder and that's how this file was stored. So that's why it has been referenced like that. But even if I rename it, I don't think it will matter as far the conflict issue I am facing.

Comment: The easiest way I suggest is go to http://www.jquery.com and download the latest library and save it in your desired folder, drag and drop onto your aspx page.

Comment: @coder:  

I find two jquery references that are good for me. What about other jquery references I have used. Are they all covered in the below two references (especially slider)? 

(a) <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

(b) <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Based on your requirement here is the http://jqueryui.com/ in this you can download custom bundle for your needs and in that folder you'll have every js file what you mentioned above.

Comment: @coder: so if I understood correctly, two googleapi reference & the jqueryui.com (which I will download) is enough to cover all my above js references (Except global.js)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the complete List of google hosted libraries and you can update them accordingly

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: I tried the steps we discussed but it is not working. I can make the URL public facing site. Please let me know if you can take a look as to what's happening?

Comment: Sure if you provide that link I can assist you further.

Comment: Are you available now?It is 1.45pm EST now.